# Manipulating Hashtable key is not working

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am trying to access a Hashtables value based on its key, which is a number as String in JSTL.
But if I increment/decrement the keys value, it does not work anymore.

I iterate the sorted list of keys in a for loop. I use this item to access Hashtable.

```
<c:forEach items="${helper:getSortedList(hashtableObj)}" var="lineNumber" varStatus="loop">
    <c:if test="${param.lineNbr eq lineNumber}">
        <c:if test="${lineNumber>1}">
            <fmt:parseNumber var="prevLineNumberKey" type="number" value="${lineNumber-1}" />
            <c:out value="PREV ${hashtableObj[prevLineNumberKey]}" escapeXml="false"/><br/>
        </c:if>
        <c:out value="Current :${lineNumber}" /><br/>
        <c:if test="${lineNumber<fn:length(hashtableObj)-1}">
            <fmt:parseNumber var="nextLineNumberKey" type="number" value="${lineNumber+1}" />
            <c:out value="NEXT ${hashtableObj[nextLineNumberKey+1]}" escapeXml="false"/><br/>
        </c:if>
</c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

The output is

> PREV 
>  Current :51
>  NEXT

But what I expected is

> PREV 50
>  Current :51
>  NEXT 52

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: getSortedList takes the Hashtable and returns sorted List<Integer>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If keys in your `Map` is `String` than to get an element you must query it with `String` value. Your current solution queries a `Map` with `Long` value.
You can convert number to `String` and then query a `Map` like this:

```
<c:set var="numberAsString">${50 - 1}</c:set>
<c:out value="value: ${hashtableObj[numberAsString]}"/>
```

Comment: Using this I could access hashtable just with modified key. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
<fmt:parseNumber var="prevLineNumberKey" type="number" value="${lineNumber-1}" />
```

With:

```
<c:set var="prevLineNumberKey">${lineNumber-1}</c:set>
```

And replace:

```
<fmt:parseNumber var="nextLineNumberKey" type="number" value="${lineNumber+1}" />
<c:out value="NEXT ${hashtableObj[nextLineNumberKey+1]}" escapeXml="false"/><br/>
```

With:

```
<c:set var="nextLineNumberKey">${lineNumber+1}</c:set>
<c:out value="NEXT ${hashtableObj[nextLineNumberKey]}" escapeXml="false"/><br/>
```

Couple of questions though:

1) Is hashtableObj really a hashtable or is it a hashmap?
2) Is the value of the hashtableObj, really a number that is equal to the key?  In other words you are expecting:

PREV 50

... that means you are expecting the *value* of the hashtable/map to be 50 AND the key is also 50?

Comment: Thanks. But hashtableObj does not seem to pick the value. 1. hashtableObj is a Hashtable. 2. The value is actually a hyperlink ( I know :) but it is a legacy app ). I just tried to keep it simple.

Comment: Try replacing: <c:out value="Current :${lineNumber}" /><br/> with <c:out value="Current :${lineNumber} / ${hashtableObj[lineNumber]}" /><br/> ... does that return anything after the slash?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.

```
    <fmt:parseNumber var="prevLineNumberKey" type="number" value="${lineNumber-1}" />
    <c:out value="Previous ${hashtableObj[sortedList[prevLineNumberKey-1]]}" escapeXml="false"/><br/>
```

I used the list element as a key for Hashtable and it works. Thanks to all answers.